# Remote Registry Reads Not Working

Tags: c#, registrykey

I've searched and found a lot of good information on remote registry reads but nothing seems to address my problem.  I've never had to ask for help before but I'm at a loss as to why I can't get my code to work.  I have a mapped drive, on the same domain, so credentials are not the issue.  I'm not getting access denied.  My code is pretty much straight from the Microsoft examples.  It should be pretty easy.

This code works with no problems:

```
            string keyname = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion";

            RegistryKey rk = RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, "COMPUTER.opr.domain.org");
            RegistryKey registryKey = rk.OpenSubKey(keyname);
            string mykey = (string)registryKey.GetValue("DevicePath");
            Console.WriteLine(mykey);
```

However, if I simply change the key as follows, it now fails with a null exception

```
            string keyname = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\Auto Update";

            RegistryKey rk = RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, "COMPUTER.opr.domain.org");
            RegistryKey registryKey = rk.OpenSubKey(keyname);
            string mykey = (string)registryKey.GetValue("RebootRequired");
            Console.WriteLine(mykey);
```

The key RebootRequired is present on the remote machine. And permissions don't seem to be an issue either.  This is also my first post so I hope I did not violate any rules.

Thoughts?

Thanks,
Rob

Comment: Are you sure you are accessing the correct registry view on the remote machine? I'm not sure how it selects which view when you don't specify it but it may be hidden in the default view that you are getting.

Comment: That particular key might also have different permissions than the CurrentVersion key... consider the behavior of a virus which wants to fiddle with WindowsUpdate, for example, and the defensive measures.

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  I believe I found the issue.  My development machine is a 32bit Windows 7.  The code I was testing on is 64bit.  Apparently Microsoft does a registry redirect when a 32bit tries to access a 64bit machine... the redirect path is to HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node and down that path the WindowsUpdate does not exist, thus giving the null exception.